# Composer: install package directly, via command line

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I need to install [sofa/eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence) Laravel **5.2** package. In the documentation there is the following instruction:

```
1. Require the package in your composer.json:

    "require": {
        "sofa/eloquence": "~5.2", // for Laravel 5.2.*
    },
```

So, I guess that after requiring it in **composer.json** I will have to run the `composer update` command. But, this command will also try to update other packages that are already installed, right?

What if I don't want that, how can I install `"sofa/eloquence": "~5.2"` without touching anything else? For example, directly, via command line (or in any other way).

Comment: composer require "name of the package"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get a package without a composer.json file use:

```
composer require sofa/eloquence:~5.2
```

You can find documentation here:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require